# What is this glowing orange spot in my attic framing?

Tags: attic

My husband and I moved into a rental house. The AC isn't working properly, and a professional told us that a pipe needs a small cut so the water flows easily for the AC to work. We cannot of course make any changes to a pipe without permission.

Every time the AC stops working (almost daily now) I or my husband have to go to the attic to flip a little cup (attached to pipes for the AC) to pour the water out and flip it back. AC starts working right away.

Now I went to the attic and noticed this orange glowing thing, first I thought it was a pipe but it has a rectangle form or maybe not all pipes are in a cylinder form?

I also thought it might be sticking out of the roof and got hot by the sun however I went to the attic in the morning (darkish outside) and it was still glowing, less bright but still glowing (see picture).

I don't know if the AC has anything to do with it and maybe this is completely normal. Orange glow looks same glow when a iron gets hot.

Any answer appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sun shining into a pipe? What time of day was this taken? Shine a flash light on it, what color is the pipe, white?

Comment: This picture was taken around 6 o'clock in the morning without any sunshine outside. It's definitely not white but when I come home I can try to upload another picture with more light on it, thank you for your fast reply and time.

Comment: Did it got lit by some light in your house? That must be the consequences of something illuminating the tube. I cannot immagine an scenario, except an chimney fire, that would make it glow by heat.. In that case the house would have burnt down long ago..

Comment: I don't think so to be honest I have no idea how long that thing is glowing inside the attic, we live here for almost 1 year and i noticed this glowing thing 2 days ago. It looks scary with all that cotton around it. We have no chimney fire

Comment: Observe it while someone switches off the main breaker. If it turns off, it's somehow connected to electric power

Comment: And if the main breaker cuts it off, then do a binary search to find out which breaker controls it. Turn off half the breakers - if still on, turn those back on and turn the other half off, if off then turn 1/2 of those on and check again. Lather, rinse, repeat. Once you have figured out which breaker controls it, see what else is on the same circuit so that (a) you know if it is OK to leave it off and (b) that may provide a clue.

Comment: Is that "a glowing thing", or light being projected from somewhere onto the wall? The latter seems more likely.

Comment: That makes completely sense. Hopefully, it is connected to something in my house. I have to figure out which breaker it is (after the main breaker test) so I can leave it off until someone fixed the problem. Hopefully, this will do the trick. I'm happy I posted on this site. Thanks again! ^^

Comment: maybe it is caused by an indicator lamp on some electrical equipment

Comment: is it hot? you could feel heat from it w/o touching if it's glowing hot. If it is indeed glowing hot, get it fixed asap.

Comment: In particular, see what any writing stamped on it says. It looks like there's some black writing in the middle, but can't make out what any of it says.

Comment: @Isherwood There's no need to be that cruel.. not everyone has a great Camara that works perfectly in the dark. It was already zoomed in a lot, which will cost some quality. The only way to get better pictures is to get closer. There is no floor to walk on, so i have to walk on rafters to get closer. To be honest, i do not trust the rafters in this house. The house is full of hidden broken things. The attic is very large..The title changed. English is not my first language. But doesn't spot means completely something else?

Comment: If it's a pipe, it may be illuminated from inside. Maybe it's an exhaust pipe from a bathroom combo fan/light/heat (e.g. an IXL Tastic). Although in my country they usually just vent into the attic void, not into a pipe. Also I didn't think PVC pipe would let any light through. It would have to be thin. It might just be a strip of light shining through a crack in the ceiling from a room in which there's a light turned on.

Comment: The left side of the attic with the orange glowing item is definitely hotter than the right side of the attic. But I can not confirm yet if it is really coming from that unknown item because we were never that close. When I turn the light off from the attic, it really glows like an extremely  hot metal part in the darkness. My husband worked with metal for 6 years, and it looks just like that. We have already contacted the company that works with the landlord. They will send someone over next week. Thank you for thinking with me ^^

Comment: You don't have to get closer if it's dangerous. Just get a brighter flashlight, or any kind of brighter light that will help the camera. You could also put the camera on the end of a long selfie stick and use its flash.  A little hokey maybe but it beats crawling through insulation.

Comment: @Isherwood Sometimes, when people are panicking about the safety of them family, they are not in the mood for some downgrading jokes. Especially as your first response on this matter. It just hits differently. Anyway, I think we should just avoid each other for now. This is going nowhere and just doesn't add anything valuable to  this topic.

Comment: We did the breaker test unfortunately it didn't make it turn off. However It looks like it was extremely affected by the heat from the sun. It is cooling down. It has a rectangular form and looks whitish/beige. I will upload a picture when it completely cools down. It is almost above the bathroom. Somebody mentioned it might be a part of the bathroom vent?

Thank you, everyone, for your quick thinking and support.

Comment: @Matt it is cooling down, and it does look like a whitish- beige color. My apologies. It looks like it was extremely affected by the heat from the sun. Any idea what this can be?

Comment: @Igby Largeman, it is located close by the bathroom (above). Somebody else mentioned the same thing as you do. So we might get somewhere ^^. It looks like the light is connected somehow with the heat from the sun. I saw an enormous light coming from it when it was really hot outside. I turned off the main breaker. And it was still shining by itself while it was also dark outside, so it couldn't be something reflecting from a crack inside the house. It might be a PVC pipe, which make me more wonder why it was glowing like that. Thank you for sharing your thoughts about this.

Comment: @Patricia It's a pipe, likely a vent stack or something. Jack wrote up a good answer. The writing on the side of it kinda gives it away. I wouldn't be concerned. Also, don't get discouraged with the comments on here, come back if you need help again!

Answer (score 10):

It's a PVC white pipe. I've got two in my attic. The 4" pipe goes through the roof and has no cover on it, probably a vent and could be used for running a snake down to unclog it. All it needs is a little daylight, or a street light/flood light to start glowing and direct sunlight really brightens it up.

[image]

[image]

Just for the heck of it, I took another picture, with the same settings, at 1:00 PM ET with the sun overhead.  The first picture was at 8 AM and just daylight.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the OP's picture again, I can just see a line on the pipe that looks like the standard printing I've seen on the PVC I've been installing lately. I'd venture to say you're correct _except_ that the OP states the pic was taken before the sun came up and that the thing is rectangular instead of round. +1 anyway.

Comment: @FreeMan  Some of that bothered  me too but I thought the  standard printing could be mistaken for a corner and in the comments the OP mentions it could be a pipe.  My neighbor's flood lights cause a slight glow...

Comment: @FreeMan How can you tell its rectangular and not a round pipe? I'm curious.

Comment: @matt. by reading the OPs description of the "thing".

Answer (score 6):

### Light.

It looks like you have a thin-walled, light color pipe coming up. The sun is shining into it, and so it looks like it's glowing. Probably a thin-wall PVC pipe, like you would usually see in drainage.

I'm guessing you have a bathroom right about there? If so, that's likely your bathroom fan vent.

Comment: It is indeed close by the bathroom (above), so it might be a PVC pipe? It was shining bright through the night without any sunlight outside and without any reflection coming from the house ( I turned off the main breaker to be sure of it). I wonder what makes it glow like that. It is cooling down outside, so is that PVC pipe? It has a rectangular form and has a whitish - beige color. I will try to make another picture when it cools down completely. Thank you for sharing this information.

Answer (score 4):

No idea about the orange thing. But I'll give you some help with the air conditioner.

An air conditioner effectively operates as a dehumidifier. The humidity removed from the air is called *condensate*. It needs to go somewhere. The good news is that with the air conditioner in the attic you should be able to rely on gravity instead of needing a pump - so one less thing to fail.

A properly designed/installed air conditioner will typically collect condensate in a pan and either have a drain pipe connected to it or a condensate pump. But just in case the pipe clogs or the pump breaks, there should be a switch that turns off the air conditioner if the pan fills up. **Your switch works!** That is a really, really good thing, because too many times the switch doesn't work (or doesn't even exist, or there is a leak just outside the pan so the pan never actually fills up to trip the switch) and you end up with a flood - which in this case would be flood the attic and eventually drip down into the rest of the house. So the air conditioner stopping a couple of times a day is actually not a *bad* thing in the grand scheme of things.

What to do about it? Putting a hole in a pipe sounds strange, but might be what is needed. More typically, if the air conditioner used to work, is that the pipe is clogged. The key though is that what you need is an HVAC technician and not a plumber. There are many people who are both, but you don't want a plumber who knows nothing about HVAC.

If you are comfortable with it, do it yourself *cleaning* may be reasonable. Google *clean condensate drain* and you can find all sorts of ways to clean condensate drains, and if this is a typical clog then one of those methods should do the trick. The catch is that it *might* turn out to be something truly broken or, if the air conditioner never really worked correctly (e.g., new installation and not tested for more than a few minutes, or previous tenant didn't bother to complain) then it might need some change to the condensate piping.

Comment: Remember, though, @Patricia, that this is a rental and that maintenance work should fall to the landlord. If you have her permission, though (get it in _writing_!) hop right to it! Cleaning a condensate drain shouldn't be a difficult task at all.

Comment: "a hole in a pipe" sounds like a hacked solution that will probably work but isn't the trap and vent that is actually required.

Answer (score 3):

> this orange glowing thing, first I thought it was a pipe but it has a rectangle form or maybe not all pipes are in a cylinder form?

Yes, pipes will be cylindrical, not rectangular.

To me, that looks like a piece of wood that is oddly colored & lit from the outside, not from any "glow" coming from the inside.

It would really help if you could

1. Get a picture that is more in focus and not so fuzzy, and
2. Get closer to the item. It's *highly* unlikely to be a rod of uranium glowing in your attic, so getting closer shouldn't cause you any harm. If you feel it, you should be able to determine if it's plastic or metal indicating it might be a pipe of some sort, or if it feels like wood, well, it's going to be wood.

It does look like your attic is quite well insulated, which is a nice bonus in a rental! Be sure to push the insulation aside to ensure you're stepping on rafters and not through the drywall attached to them, then fluff the insulation back up after you've had a closer inspection.

Comment: The only way to make a clearer  picture is to get close to it. This is a bit risky to me because the house has a lot of reparations done in a very poor cheap way. I will try to make close-up picture tonight. However, if that fails, I definitely like the idea of turning the main breaker as soon as possible off to see if it will help.

Comment: I smelled two times a fire smell in the house around 3-4 weeks ago but couldn't find anything. Now that we just discovered this issue, I just hope it doesn't link to each other.

Next week, someone will come over to check things out. That way, we are sure what's going on. 

Thank you for your time and feedback ^^

Comment: A) that is _not_ the glow of embers of wood on fire. B) If something in your house _were_ on fire 3-4 weeks ago, you would _definitely_ have known by now.